# Dates changing when I change another date

Tags: javascript, date, object

so I 'm having a strange bug here related to changing the month of a date object. here is the code.

```
let date = new Date();
let captions = [];

for (let i=0; i < 12; i++) {
  let newDate = date;
  newDate.setMonth(date.getMonth() - i);
  let month = newDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
  let year = newDate.getFullYear();

  captions.push({month, year});
}
```

The thing is value of date variable is changing every loop. I can understand why.

Anyone?

Comment: Because `=` doesn't clone the Date object, it just creates a separate reference **to the same object** (this is nothing specific to Date objects btw, it's how all objects work in JS).

Comment: Nice! Get it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with this assignment: `let newDate = date;`

What happens is that now newDate is a <s>reference to your original `date` variable.</s>

As **Lennholm** suggested in his comment below:

> "it's not a reference to the original variable but to the same object
>   (in memory) that the original variable also references. The two
>   variables are independent of each other."

To avoid that change it to this: `let newDate = new Date(date);`

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-z82omh).

Comment: *"newDate is a reference to your original date variable"* – This is a bit misleading, it's not a reference to the original variable but to the same object (in memory) that the original variable also references. The two variables are independent of each other.

Comment: Thank you @Lennholm. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This made totally sense!